# Understanding Norton' s dome equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics, arc-length

Here is the equation of Norton's dome used to demonstrate an indeterministic system within Newtonian formalism:

h(r) = $-\frac{2}{3g}r^{\frac{3}{2}}$

where r is defined as "radial distance coordinate".

I struggle to understand this equation- I presume r really just stands for arc length but in this case how can it serve as an independent variable ? Is it possible to introduce standard Cartesian coordinates (so h becomes y) and rewrite this equation in x-y terms ?

Another (possibly related) question concerns the application of Newton' s equation of motion. The author states that

$sin(\theta) = \frac{dh}{dr}$

where $\theta$ is the angle between the tangent to the surface in the radial direction in horizontal.

How come this is the case ? How to bind this derivative with the geometry of our picture ?

If anything, I am referring to this paper (pages 2-4):

[http://www.pitt.edu/~jdnorton/papers/DomePSA2006.pdf](http://www.pitt.edu/%7Ejdnorton/papers/DomePSA2006.pdf)

Any help will be much appreciated !!!